# Batch parameter must be a JSON array

Tags: php, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Im trying to make following BATCH request on Facebook Graph API

I encode this using urlencode

/?batch=[{"method":"POST","relative_url":"23843240845450549","body":"end_time=2019-03-29T19:59:59-0300&lifetime_budget=5328"}]

This is the encoded request

/?batch=%5B%7B%22method%22%3A%22POST%22%2C%22relative_url%22%3A%226118436634612%22%2C%22body%22%3A%22end_time%3D2019-03-29T19%3A59%3A59-0300&lifetime_budget=328921%22%7D%5D

But i get

"Batch parameter must be a JSON array",

I know the error is around the '&', Im unable to find the way to put multiple fields on body request

Have also tried

/?batch=[{"method":"POST","relative_url":"23843240845450549","body":"end_time=2019-03-29T19:59:59-0300&lifetime_budget=5328"}]

and also

/?batch=[{"method":"POST","relative_url":"23843240845450549","body":"end_time=2019-03-29T19:59:59-0300&amplifetime_budget=5328"}]

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found that i had to encode the & into %26

So this is working:

/?batch=%5B%7B%22method%22%3A%22POST%22%2C%22relative_url%22%3A%226118436634612%22%2C%22body%22%3A%22end_time%3D2019-03-29T19%3A59%3A59-0300%26lifetime_budget%3D328921%22%7D%5D